# Show Youtube comments in terminal?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

How to view youtube comments in terminal ?

I tried using text based browsers like Lynx and w3m but to no avail .

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CNRRdyFwsY (and other videos by gotbletu) which points to https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer and for Ubuntu there's a ppa (link on the github page).

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to read those?

Comment: @DK Bose it works with --comments flag !  Put this as an answer .

Comment: Will do in a few minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a video by gotbletu, [youtube-viewer - Watch, Read and Post Youtube Comments - Linux CLI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CNRRdyFwsY), the *youtube-viewer* application can do what you want. You may add the Webupd8.org ppa using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` and then install the *youtube-viewer* package for your version of Ubuntu.

---

The earlier video by gotbletu on YouTube Viewer is [Youtube-Viewer -- Search and Play Youtube Video - Linux CLI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnJ67oAxVQ4) and a detailed review from 2015 is [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/youtube-viewer-complete-youtube-client.html).

---

I followed the instructions and installed *youtube-viewer* and its dependencies on Lubuntu 19.04.

I ran `youtube-viewer --comments 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVzGZo5kS8c'` to look at the comments for that video.

[image: Comments displayed in youtube-viewer]

At the same time, I also viewed the video in Firefox 69:

[image: Comments displayed in Firefox]

- youtube-viewer seems to default to displaying comments chronologically, newest first. So I sorted the comments in Firefox the same way.
- youtube-viewer seems to only display comments but not their replies as can be seen by comparing the highlighted areas in the images. So if one is interested in viewing replies as well, then a full-fledged browser maybe needed.